# C++ OpenGL --- Linker error with function gluBuild2DMipmaps

Tags: c++, opengl

```
Additional Information:
#include <gl\glu.h>
#include <gl\gl.h>
```

Hey, I got a really simple but soul-destroying problem:

I can compile a normal opengl program (rotating triangles) with dev++, but if I want to use the function gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, 0, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0), a linker error occurs

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to `gluBuild2DMipmaps@28´
Id returned 1 exit status
[Build error] [myprog.exe] Error 1
```

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try linking against `glu32.lib`.